# Html helpers project visible by another project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I need to put my html helpers created in a separate project and I want those Helpers to be visible and usable in another project.
How we can do this .is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know if you creating your own `HtmlHelper` you should create static class in `System.Web.Mvc.Html` `namespace`.

So nobody forbids you to crate **library type** project (dll) in VS, create all your helpers there and then add refference to your MVC projects where you need your helpers.